# Mapping through array of objects and displaying as html

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, object, expo

I am trying to map through some images and display them as HTML for a pdf markup.  I am getting undefined as of now.

my array of images

```
morePictures": Array [
    Object {
      "Picture": "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2124B18A-AD51-4720-9D7E-7DB51C468579/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540arod1207%252FAOS/Camera/087FD3A3-E875-4F80-A9DB-C7BC66F17574.jpg",
    },
    Object {
      "Picture": "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2124B18A-AD51-4720-9D7E-7DB51C468579/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540arod1207%252FAOS/Camera/681E088D-F63D-4E16-8889-07F098909289.jpg",
    },
  ],
```

changing images to base64 and setting state allImages into an array useState([])

```
 form.morePictures.map(async (pic) => {
      const morePicturesAsset = Asset.fromModule(pic.Picture);
      const morePictureImages = await manipulateAsync(
        morePicturesAsset.localUri ?? morePicturesAsset.uri,
        [],
        {
          base64: true,
          compress: 1,
          format: SaveFormat.PNG,
        }
      );
      setAllImages(morePictureImages);
    });
```

Attempting to loop through the images and outputting as html

```
//map through images //
    const multiImage = () =>
      allImages
        .map((pic) => {
          return `  
    <td>
    <img
    src="data:image/jpg;base64,${pic.base64}"
    style="width: 40vw;" />
    </td>
    `;
        })
        .join("");
```

calling the function multiImage

```
<tr>
                        <td>Pictures</td>
                        <td>
                        <img
                        src="data:image/jpg;base64,${pictureImage.base64}"
                        style="width: 40vw;" />
                    </td>
                        ${multiImage()}

                    </tr>
```

Comment: This is tagged as `react-native` and `expo` but it doesn't look like it's even using React at all?

Comment: I could have probably used some better tags,  with the expo print function, I am using it to create a pdf which is in HTML

Answer (score 0):

For React Native and Expo you could use:

```
{allImages.map((item, index) => (
  <td key={index}></td>
 ))}
```